# Select rows in a dataframe based on number of columns equal to True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to identify all rows, where 4 from 5 columns are True i.e.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        ],
        index=["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mnl"],
        columns=list("abcde")
    ).applymap(bool)
```

So that....

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        ],
        index=["ghi", "mnl"],
        columns=list("abcde")
    ).applymap(bool)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum` of columns and compare by number of values, here `4` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df.sum(axis=1).eq(4)])
        a     b     c      d      e
ghi  True  True  True   True  False
mnl  True  True  True  False   True
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.sum(axis=1))
abc    0
def    5
ghi    4
jkl    0
mnl    4
dtype: int64
```

If want `4` or `5` matched Trues:

```
print (df[df.sum(axis=1).isin([4,5])])
        a     b     c      d      e
def  True  True  True   True   True
ghi  True  True  True   True  False
mnl  True  True  True  False   True
```

If want greater or equal of 4:

```
print (df[df.sum(axis=1).ge(4)])
        a     b     c      d      e
def  True  True  True   True   True
ghi  True  True  True   True  False
mnl  True  True  True  False   True
```

Comment: If you want to state certain condition like "Where all but (x) columns are true" you can replace the `4` in with `len(list(df)) - x` , right Jezrael?